# About a proof with respect to completeness of Representation of $GL_n\mathbb{C}$

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Question:

1.Between (15.48) and (15.49), it writes:
For w $\in \mathbb{C}$, let L(w) be the one-dimentional representation of $\mathfrak{sl}_n\mathbb{C}\times \mathbb{C}$

why here w occur?

2. (15.49)
   \begin{align*}
     \rho: SL_n\mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C}  &\to GL_n\mathbb{C} \\
        g\times z &\mapsto e^z\cdot g
   \end{align*}
   To get the kernel of $\rho$
   \begin{align*}
     e^z\cdot g&= I\\
         g&= e^{-z}\\
     \det{g}&=e^{-nz}=1=e^{2\pi ik}  \\
          z&=\frac{-2\pi ik}{n}\\ 
       s&=-z=\frac{2\pi ik}{n} 
   \end{align*}
   But the book writes: $s=-z=\frac{2\pi i}{n}$

[image]

[image]

Proposition 9.17:
Let g be a complex lie algebra, $\mathfrak{g_{ss}}=\mathfrak{g}/\text{Rad}(\mathfrak{g})$. Every irreducible representation of $ \mathfrak{g}$ is of the form $V=V_0\otimes L$, where $V_0$ is an irreducible representation of $\mathfrak{g_{ss}}$, and L is a one-dimentional representation.

Comment: The wording of your question is not very clear but I think I understand what you are asking. For 1. the idea here is that representations of $\mathfrak{gl}$ break down as tensor products of reps of $\mathfrak{sl}$ and reps of the scalar matrices. The latter reps are exactly these $L(w)$. In more detail we can specify a representation of $\mathbb{C}$ by $\rho(t)(v) := (wt)v$ i.e. as multiplication rescaled by $w$.

Comment: 2. They say **generated by** $s = e^{2\pi i/n}$ so that means all $s^k = e^{2\pi ik/n}$

Comment: @Callum Is $GL_n{C}\cong SL_nC\times C^*$?

Comment: No they just have the same Lie algebras. Look in the text you've posted they say that $GL_n\mathbb{C}$ is a quotient of $SL_n\mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C}$ by a discrete subgroup of the centre. Indeed $SL_n\mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C}$ is exactly the universal cover of $GL_n\mathbb{C}$. In other words it is the simply connected group here

Comment: so why we can see whether two irrep. of $ GLn_\mathbb{C}$ are isomorphic or not by their restriction under $SL_n\mathbb{C}$ and   center $C^∗$ respectively

Comment: Because irreps of $GL_n$ are those irreps of $SL_n \times \mathbb{C}^*$ which are trivial on the discrete subgroup of the centre and representations of $G\times H$ are of the form $V\otimes W$ where $V$ is a $G$-rep and $W$ is a $H$-rep and the action is defined to be: $(g,h)(v\otimes w) := gv \otimes hw$. Thus for any $G\times H$-rep we only need to check they agree for $G\times\{e\}$ and $\{e\}\times H$